# Adding JavaScript libraries to Sonar

Tags: javascript, html, sonarqube

Is there a way of adding JavaScript libraries to Sonar? I found that we can define undefined variables in 'General Settings' option, but couldn't find a way to tell Sonar that I have used a specific library like Backbone.js, jQuery, etc.

I have used Sonar JavaScript plugin and everything else works perfect.

Comment: Why would you like to specify these libraries? What's you case?

Comment: @ppapapetrou - OP is probably seeing "undefined variables" being reported in some js files when the variables are actually defined in the library file. At least that's why *I* would like an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [the newest version of the JavaScript plugin will support JQuery and NodeJS:](http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/Sonar-JavaScript-Plugin-for-jQuery-and-Node-JS-code-validation-tp4998914p4998963.html)

> New version of JavaScript plugin will be able to check jQuery and
>   NodeJS projects

**edit:** I was running version 0.4 of the JavaScript plugin. [Version 1.0](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JavaScript+Plugin) is the current version and it does seem to support at least JQuery.